# Getting Wrong Result in Sparql

Tags: sparql, ontology

I am try to Implement a Sparql Query which will give some result.I am trying to Implement Like this:
My Data points are below from where I getting the data:

**Subject:**

```
<http://rhizomik.net/semanticxbrl/0001397832_agph-20110930/Context_9ME_30-Sep-2011/ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock/>
```

**Predicate:**

```
<http:// www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
```

**Object:**

```
<http://www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock>
```

My Query is

```
PREFIX ab: <http:// www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#>

SELECT ?node ?val_type ?value 
  WHERE {
     ?node ab:val_type ?val_type .
     ?node ab:value ?value .
  }
```

I want to get the result of all subject predicate and object.I am new to sparql.please help me out

Comment: what result do you get?
what sparql endpoint/triple store/application are you sending your queries to?

Comment: I dont get any result.its showing empty result.

Comment: @ASHISHRANJAN Than something in your query is wrong. Is `ab:val_type` or `ab:value` available in your data?

Comment: See i want a simple which picks the subject predicate on the basis of the Object.Please give me soulution

Comment: I am using It on jena Apache Fuseki Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * WHERE 
{ 
  ?s ?p <http://www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock> 
}
```

Comment: Will not work, you forgot the `<>` around the URI which will get you a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

In SPARQL everything with a `?` in front of it is a variable. If you want everything from the subject, predicate and object you can do it like this:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
```

But then you list everything. When you want to only list the values of your given subject you will have to do it like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE { <http://rhizomik.net/semanticxbrl/0001397832_agph-20110930/Context_9ME_30-Sep-2011/ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock/> ?p ?o }
```

And your query could easily be formatted to something like this:

```
PREFIX ab: <http:// www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#>

SELECT ?s ?valType ?value WHERE { 
  ?s ab:val_type ?valType ;
     ab:value ?value .
}
```

Where `;` marks when you want to include something else in your query with your given subject, but `.` marks the end of your query. If you want more information about how SPARQL works or how you can query check out the Euclid project with webinar recording: [Querying linked data, 2013-03-04](http://www.euclid-project.eu/resources/webinars-recordings) or just test it yourself on a SPARQL endpoint like from [FactForge](http://factforge.net/sparql).

To reflect my comment below:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p <http://www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock> }
```

will select everything with the given object.

Comment: @Dear Alex: Please Help me ,I want to pick the data on the basis of object URI.

Comment: See my edited post above for selecting everything with a given object.

Comment: Thanks Alex.I need one more help..from you If I am having more than one object corresponding subject then what will be the query.The objects are: <http://www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#ConvertibleNotesPayableTextBlock>
<http://www.atlanticgreenpower.com/20110930#DerivativeLiabilityWarrants>

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, can you post the result you are getting?

Comment: No I will not give you my mail address, anyway. I don't know if you have more than one of the same objects in your dataset. That's up to you to figure out...

Comment: @AshishRanjan If you have a new question ask it as a new question referencing back to this question if relevant